# How to share video stream with friends online?

Tags: video, video-streaming, streaming, screensharing

There are a few online courses that I would like to watch with friends, meaning that I want to play the videos on my computer and share the streaming content real-time with a couple of people.

I am thinking about something like screen sharing with audio from the computer, not the microphone.

How do I go about to do that? What software would you recommend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most standard web video conferencing solutions will allow you share your screen including any videos playing.

If the videos are encrypted and DRM protected then most likely the video will not show in the shared session, although you may hear the audio. This is by design as the owner of the courses may not want to share the content without users signing up.